# Semiconductor structure confinement modes

Tags: optics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, laser, light-emitting-diodes

Today, I would like to simulate the **field intensity in an emitting structure** such as a laser diode. With this field, I will be able to calculate the confinement factor of my device.

I put an illustration of what I want to achieve just here :
*I want to obtain my transverse field intensity (red curve) form my structure (blue curve)*

[image: Text]

Has anyone ever done such **calculations / simulations** ? If this is the case, please, can you give me some related technics to achieve this ?

Thanks for your help,
Dj1312.

Comment: You you want to know the spatial optical E-field profile for a 1D structure? There are many such simulation tools. I’ve used CAMFR I the past, http://camfr.sourceforge.net but any 1D transfer matrix method will let you do this, unless I’ve misunderstood your question.

Comment: I have an issue to understand the theory behind the resolution… I don't understand how we can deduce the "solution" only using matrix defined by the material.

Comment: Discretise the problem at the spacial resolution you require, write a matrix for each slice, solve.